# cURL 56 error on PayPal Sandbox but not on PayPal Live

Tags: symfony, curl, paypal

We have a symfony web application that uses sylius/omnipay bundle to handle PayPal payments.On production site everything works fine, but on the staging server,that uses PayPal sandbox account, we have started getting **curl error 56** every time we try to make a test payment. This is the full error:

`[curl] 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104    [url] https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=85.0&USER=info_api1.test_sit.com&PWD=MFNP7LQ0WIUADDN3&SIGNATURE=LOcWoI31C7fd0v3bKAYDRl9PRl31QrxRG3M066cE7DSKs9FIhe0-1t8E&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=20.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM=19499&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing&NOSHIPPING=1&ALLOWNOTE=0&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.site.com%2Forder%2Fconfirmed&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test.com%2Forder%2Fconfirmed`

At first we thought that something is wrong with OpenSSL on the staging machine, but when we connected the app on staging server with the production PayPal account everything went trough without any problems. Now I'm not sure is something wrong with the configuration of our staging server or what...
Anyone any ides?